# backbone.js el: 'jqueySelector' doesn't catch parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following code in a Marionette ItemView definition:

```
class AdProductDetailsView extends Marionette.ItemView

  el: '#product-details'
  template: =>
     price =
        amount: if @model.get('price') then @model.get('price').get('amount') else 0
        currency: if @model.get('price') then @model.get('price').get('currency') else 'BOB'
     AdProductDetailsTemplate
        price: Currency.format price.amount, price.currency
        contact: @model.get('contact')?.toJSON()
        location: @model.get('location')?.toJSON()
```

The thing is that the page doesn't "execute" the el: '#product-details' property. I've once ago tried to put it in the view's instantiation in another code, but I tried it and it didn't work. When I run this code, nothing appears on the screen, however, if I run it without el:..., the view is created and inserted in its own div, and it's this div wich I don't really want. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably need to show more code. As Patrick said, the `el` MUST be in the DOM when the view is being created, and it seems like that's not the case. How is the "#product-details" DOM created in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a race condition, since you are assigning this view to `#product-details`, it needs to exist in the DOM before you instantiate that view.

This would explain why without `el` it works, because backbone creates a DOM element if one isn't defined.